# How to convert byte data to double or float?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have a 4 `byte` data`[80 34 52 42]`. How do I convert this into a `double` or `float` in C#? The actual conversion should give an approximate value of about `50`.

Comment: See BitConverter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.bitconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`BitConverter.ToSingle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tosingle(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
float f = BitConverter.ToSingle(new byte[] { 0x80, 0x34, 0x52, 0x42 }, 0);
```

The value of `f` would be `52.55127`.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thanks for your help,it works. I'm trying to write a function to do that.But it doesn't seem to work long value = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < mybyteArray.Length;i++ )
            {
                value=(value<<8)+(mybyteArray[i] & 0xff);
            }